# can not resolve method addOnCompleteListener

Tags: android, firebase

I'm developing a social media type app it has firebase connections too. suddenly i get this error:

> can not resolve method .addOnCompleteListener() .

I tried invalidate cache and restart , rebuilding project , sync project again also deleting inside .gradle folder and rebuilding nothing woreked.

these are images of some project files i can provide more if needed.

RegisterActivity.java
  [RegisterActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyU6K.png)

RegisterActivity.java import area
[RegisterActivity.java import area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPJks.png)

build.gradle(module app)
[build.gradle(module app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1MmR.png)

build.grale(project)
[build.grale(project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lEkQ.png)

code for RegisterActivity.java

```
package com.socialnetwork.socialnet;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;



public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private EditText UserEmail, UserPassword, UserConfirmPassword;
private Button CreateAccountButton;
private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    UserEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_email);
    UserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password);
    UserConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_confirm_password);
    CreateAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_create_account);
    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);


    CreateAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            CreateNewAccount();
        }
    });
}



private void CreateNewAccount()
{
    String email = UserEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = UserPassword.getText().toString();
    String confirmPassword = UserConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your email...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmPassword))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please confirm your password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "your password do not match with your confirm password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        loadingBar.setTitle("Creating New Account");
        loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are creating your new Account...");
        loadingBar.show();
        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            SendUserToSetupActivity();

                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "you are authenticated successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error Occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}



private void SendUserToSetupActivity()
{
    Intent setupIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
    setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(setupIntent);
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: When asking questions on Stack Overflow, you should copy the relevant code into the question instead of linking to it.

Comment: ok thanks i can do that

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `this` keyword. Try

`.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
     ....
}`

Check the Sign Up New Users section of [Set up Firebase Authentication for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/) and you'll see where you are missing it

**Or try**

I've checked for differences between your code and mine and the only important difference is in the app build.gradle file where I implement this

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'`

and you don't.
Try implementing that.

Comment: i tried but error still the same .   tutorial that  i'm following also doesn't have "this"  this is the video link.  please watch time 8.40  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHbV6kNkMC4&index=9&list=PLxefhmF0pcPnTQ2oyMffo6QbWtztXu1W_  you can see the whole project and help me. thanks.

Comment: @Dominic: there is also an `addOnCompleteListener` overload that takes just the listener: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E)

Comment: im new to app development  i didn't understand what u said. where to put this addOnCompleteListener   and is it solve my error ?

Comment: Okay. I don't really get this. I've checked for differences between your code and mine and the only important difference is in the app build.gradle file where I implement this 

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'`
and you don't. Could you try that?

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. I didn't notice that